# Compilation issue with boost library

Tags: c++, boost, linker-errors, undefined-reference, boost-regex

I am trying to compile some source codes. However it is throwing some error related to boost library. Here is the error

```
undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_mem_block()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x40a6): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::verify_options(unsigned int, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x40db): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::put_mem_block(void*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x430a): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::put_mem_block(void*)'
main.o: In function `_ZN7Command12createVectorIdEEvRKSsRSt6vectorIT_SaIS4_EES4_.constprop.1207':
main.cpp:(.text+0x436e): undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x439f): undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x43d0): undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<
```

I have the boost regex library installed in my system and I have given the path to the library using -L option and specified the library using -lboost_regex option as well. What could be the issue?

It does find the library. But still throwing an error

Comment: Have you tried adding `-lboost_regex`? (without the 'lib').

Comment: what is the actual compiler command?

Comment: g++ main.cpp -lboost_regex -lboost_iostreams -L/usr/lib -o main.o

Comment: do you want to statically or dynamically link boost?

Comment: I want to statically link boost

Comment: What does your #include directive look like?

Comment: I have fixed the issue. Actually, I was using the make file in the source code. But now I manually gave the path to the library and compiler parameters without using the make file. I am not sure about the issues with make file though

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, and it has been solved. So maybe you had installed an older version of boost before, and the linker linkes the older version.

Try to remove all installed boost library, and reinstall the boost library, your problem will be solved.